# How to show directions in MapComponent in Codenameone

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, codenameone

I have been able to Display a map with corodinates using Codenameone and Netbeans, now i want to add 2 points and map a direction/route similar to google maps directions.

Does anyone have a sample code for this using the MapComponent with google maps api?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

That's not supported by maps within your application, however you can launch the devices turn by turn navigation app using the [Display.openNativeNavigationApp(lat,lon)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#openNativeNavigationApp-double-double-) API.